# Jquery Event Not Getting Triggered for Table Cell in Modified DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a simple Jquery script which populates an empty table with lots of rows and cells.

Depending on the state of a checkbox I want to toggle a CSS class for all cells within the newly populated table (not there when the page loads, but dynamically created by a JS function upon a form submit).

I am able to set up a "click" event on the table cells and it works fine.

But my attempts at using `on()` to bind a function to a `hover()` event have not been successful. The event never seems to get triggered and no console log message produced. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

```
$("#resultTable").click(function(e){  // This function works fine.
        $(e.target).closest('td').toggleClass('stay');
    });

$("#resultTable td").on("hover", //Same problem for a simpler 'mouseover'
    function(event){
        console.log("MOUSE OVER"); //Never appears
        $(this).toggleClass('over');
    },
    function(event){
        console.log("MOUSE OUT"); //Never appears
        $(this).toggleClass('over');
    }
    );
```

Comment: I'm using 1.7.1 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dynamically inserting rows into the table then `.on` will not work if its binded to the tds that come into existence after the binding happens. From the docs When the call to `.on` is made the element to which the event is binded must exist in the DOM when the binding happens.

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

This might work

```
$j(document).on("hover", "#resultTable td",
    function(event){
        console.log("MOUSE OVER"); //Never appears
        $(this).toggleClass('over');
    },
    function(event){
        console.log("MOUSE OUT"); //Never appears
        $(this).toggleClass('over');
    }
    );
```

If you are only adding the rows dynamically then you can attach the event to `#resultTable` to make the delegation a bit faster.

Comment: Wonderful. This worked perfectly. Also thanks for taking the time to  explain the principles behind it!

Answer (score 0):

Try `delegate`..not sure with the version that supports `on`

```
$("#resultTable").delegate("td","mouseover", function(event){
        console.log("MOUSE OVER"); //Never appears
        $(this).addClass('over');
    });

$("#resultTable").delegate("td","mouseout",function(event){
        console.log("MOUSE OUT"); //Never appears
        $(this).removeClass('over');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, this didn't work for me

Comment: Make sure your table id `resultTable` is the same